# Можно ли как то вызвать определенный класс по параметру

Tags: php

Например объект `$test->{$str}` так вызывается метод через параметр в `str`, а мне нужно как то создать объект класса определенного через параметр. Например `$str = "test1"; $obj = new {$str}()`. Сори за оформление пол третьего утра, пишу с телефона под одеялом, пока жена спит, а эта мысль не дает уснуть.

Comment: Пример был почти правильный, но фигурные не нужны: ``$obj = new $str();``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример №3 из [документации к PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new):

> Если с директивой new используется строка (string), содержащая имя класса, то будет создан новый экземпляр этого класса. Если имя находится в пространстве имен, то оно должно быть задано полностью.

```
$instance = new SimpleClass();

$className = 'SimpleClass';
$instance = new $className(); // new SimpleClass()
```

Comment: А не подскажете как отловить ошибку отсутствия класса, try  catch не помогает

Comment: Выполняйте проверку ``class_exists($className)``. Или, если у вас php7, ловите ``EngineException``

Comment: @xEdelwess дзякуй помогло